# Adding a custom font in QGIS Windows

Tags: qgis, labeling, layouts, font

I have added 'montserrat' into my OSGeo4W64 folder but I'm not sure how/where to add it so I can use it in my project.

Comment: on windows you can install the font QGIS needs to be re-launched to pick up the new font that have been installed. https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-install-fonts-in-windows-10/